# in bash, how to quickly replace a number in a file?

Tags: bash, sed

my terraform tf file, one line has:

```
green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 0
```

I want to replace it with `$blue_nodes_asg_instance_count` = `3`, the result should be:

```
green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 3
```

I tried this but does not work:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)green_nodes_asg_instance_count\(.*\)=\(.*\)0/\1green_nodes_asg_instance_count\2=\3\$blue_nodes_asg_instance_count/g' test.tf
```

Comment: So the line should become `green_nodes_asg_instance_count = $blue_nodes_asg_instance_count=3` or what? Your replacement string doesn't have that `=3` at all.

Comment: using the $blue_nodes_asg_instance_count=3 to replace it, the result should be:  green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 3,  and keep any spaces between them, just replace the number.

Comment: What relevance does the word "quickly" (in the title) have here? Do you need to do it _atomically_ (possibly locking the file first)?

Comment: `sed -ri 's/green_nodes_asg_instance_count(.*=.*)0/green_nodes_asg_instance_count\1'"$blue_nodes_asg_instance_count"'/g' test.tf` (You have to actually expand the shell variable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's useless to include `\(.*\)` at the beginning of a pattern just to replace it by itself.
- The same applies for the second and third group. You replace them by themselves
- You also replace `green_nodes_asg_instance_count` by `green_nodes_asg_instance_count`. Again not very helpful

If you want to turn

```
green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 0
```

into

```
green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 3
```

Then change nothing but the `0` with

```
sed '/green_nodes_asg_instance_count *= *0/s/0/3/' test.tf
```

- `/green_nodes_asg_instance_count *= *0/` is an *address*, which means the following command is executed only on lines that match the regular expression. I added `*` after the whitespaces to make any number of whitespaces optional
- `s/0/3/` `s`ubstitutes the `0` with your replacement

Comment: May be worth noting that strictly speaking, that would replace `0012# green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 0` with `3012# green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 0` for instance. I.e, it assumes there's no other occurrence of `0` before the match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
perl -pi -e 's{\bgreen_nodes_asg_instance_count\s*=\s*\K.*}{3}' your-file
```

To change everything after `green_nodes_asg_instance_count<optional-whitespace>=<optional-whitespace>` to `3` (and provided that it's not following a word character to avoid replacing it in `olive_green_nodes_asg_instance_count = 123` for instance).

That should be more portable than using the non-standard `-i` extension of `sed` (with incompatible behaviour between implementations that support it), and means you can use the more advanced PCRE than `sed`'s default BRE.